# Compositing images while preserving focus blur

Tags: photo-editing, compositing

I want to fix the camera in a static scene and take a few photos of objects, to later composite them into a single image. Some objects overlap in the image plane, and there is significant focus blue due to aperture opening.

What techniques help in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanations you can use stacking. For this purpose you create in Photoshop new image (with dimensions of photos you want to stack), add all of your images as layers, add to each layer mask and using brush on mask "remove" some elements from each layer/photo. Moving up/down layers you can adjust the appearance of the objects in the end image

Comment: That's a problem when objects overlap with some blur at the edges, as the original backgrounds need to be removed and some alpha blending needs to take place.

Comment: And some play with fethering of the brush can help also to smooth the intersection between objects and objects/background